# Cant connect to SQL Server 2008 from Window XP SP2 But work fine with SP3 and 7 and above?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-xp, sql-server-2008-r2

Yesterday our windows server 2008 R2 Updated after 7 years!
After that our Windows XP SP2 and Lower clients reported that the ERP software cant connect to server! 
But Windows 7 and above clients still work!

After digging internet I found this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-ae/help/839269/you-may-not-be-able-to-connect-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-that-is-co

I found two solution:
1. Add SQL port to Connection String.
2. Add a "Data Source" from "Control Panel" -> "Adminitrative Tools" -> "Data Sources(ODBC)"
In User DSN click "Add"
Select "SQL Server" (Last One) and click "Finish"
Fill the Name and Description Randomly and Enter the Server Name or IP with SQL instance like "192.168.1.2\MSSQLSERVER" and click "Next"
Click "Client Configuration"
In there un check "Dynamically determine port" and enter the SQL port Number (Fore default its 1433) and "OK"
Click "Next" and there will be an error but the problem solved!

You can do this from Registry:
Add this key:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo]
and Add "String" with name of your SQL Server (like "192.168.1.2\MSQLSERVER") and Value of "DBMSSOCN,192.168.1.1\green,1433"

Comment: Did either of these solutions work for you?

Comment: Yes, And I just wrote it here for others.